# GC overhead limit exceeded inside IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting the same build failure when I try to run a gradle task to setup a modding workspace for minecraft.

I imported my build.gradle file into IntelliJ IDEA. When I run the task `setupDecompWorkspace` from within IntelliJ it runs for a few minutes and then fails with an error `GC overhead limit exceeded`.

One recommendation I read was to increase the heap size for IntelliJ. I increased the heap from 750m to 2G just to see if that made an difference. After rerunning the same task I got the same error.

I am finding quite a few references to this error in other contexts but not for anything in my specific use case. Am I looking in the wrong place to solve the issue?

Also the gradle task completes with no issue if I use a Windows / Linux shell and run `gradlew.bat setupDecompWorkspace`. But I am looking to solve the issue of why I cannot get IntelliJ to cooperate.

Any advice?

**EDIT**

I changed the default GC from ConMarkSweepGC to G1 just to see if it would make any difference, it did not.

I think changes were made to the version of FernFlower used in the decomp process which is where the issues is stemming from.

Comment: Have you tried giving more memory to your jvm via JAVA_OPTS ?

Comment: Actually I just found a bit of documentation that talks about how if this error occurs that people have fixed it by increasing the Gradle heap size. That appears to have worked.

Comment: How did you do that?